# Add a badge on icon in Ionic 3

Tags: css, ionic-framework, sass, ionic2, ionic3

I need to add a number badge to the cart icon in ionic 3 so that the user gets the update of number of elements in the cart without actually visiting the page i tried to use the code of button and badge together but it was of no use

```
  <button ion-button icon-only (click)="cart()">
      <ion-icon name="cart"> <ion-badge item-end>260k</ion-badge></ion-icon>
  </button>
```

Above code displays the badge next to the cart icon but not over it, so is there a way to add badge to the icon itself like we have in notification alert badges?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you will have to use some CSS and absolute positioning to place the badge above the left corner of the cart icon.

Something like this:

```
<button id="cart-btn" ion-button icon-only (click)="cart()">
      <ion-icon name="cart"></ion-icon>
      <ion-badge id="cart-badge">260k</ion-badge>
</button>
```

CSS

```
#cart-btn {
   position: relative;
}

#cart-badge {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0px;
   right: 0px;
}
```

Comment: You have a typo in your answer. It should be position:absolute.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the typo Michael.D and Florian for the edit.

Comment: You can save some html by not giving any id to the ion-badge and write it's css deceleration block directly inside the #cart-btn.

Comment: @Samiullah Indeed! There are many ways it can be written. I set the id on ion-badge for clarity. I think its fine for an example. I usually use sass so I would normally nest ion-badge inside #cart-btn.

Comment: @Jack whether it's me or it's common, I feel silly when I write custom css and try to use as much ionic framework as I could.

Comment: @Samiullah Khan In Sass you can nest the selector but not in CSS which is what is shown in my example.

Comment: @Michael.D - How to display badge onApplication icon in ionic ?

Comment: how do I show the badge in the bottom right corner?

Comment: @ir2pid Change top: 0px; to bottom: 0px;

Answer (score 3):

Try this one

Template:

```
  <div>
        <button id="notification-button" ion-button clear>
            <ion-icon name="notifications">
              <ion-badge id="notifications-badge" color="danger">7</ion-badge>
            </ion-icon>              
        </button>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
  #notification-button {            
            position: relative;
            width: 42px;
            top:1px;
            right: 1px;
            overflow: visible!important;
        }


   #notifications-badge {
            background-color: red;
            position: absolute;
            top: -3px;
            right: -3px;
            border-radius: 100%;
        }
```

Comment: This is what i was looking. Thanks Man

Answer (score 0):

With the last version of Ionic (Ionic 4), this does the job perfectly:

```
<ion-tabs>

  <ion-tab-bar slot="bottom">

    <ion-tab-button tab="profile">
      <ion-icon name="person"></ion-icon>
      <ion-badge color="danger">8</ion-badge>
      <ion-label>profile</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button tab="settings">
      <ion-icon name="settings"></ion-icon>
      <ion-badge color="warning">3</ion-badge>
      <ion-label>Market</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>

  </ion-tab-bar>

</ion-tabs>
```

Reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q6ojtDFOaKA

Comment: This only works on` ion-tab-button` not on `ion-icon` per se.

Answer (score 0):

for ionic 5 this work perfectly for me :

```
<ion-buttons slot="start" (click)="whateverYouWant()">
    <ion-icon slot="start" name="mail"></ion-icon>
    <ion-badge color="danger" style="position: absolute; right: -5px; top: -3px;">3
    </ion-badge>
</ion-buttons>
```

PS : in my case it is place in a ion-item

[preview result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQR2W.png)